# Django: Allow Users With Permission to Edit Project Page

Tags: python, django, permissions

I have a model: uProjects that associates a user and a project and if that user has admin status, i.e. ifAdmin. I am trying to create a way to allow a user to editproject if that user has ifAdmin=True for that project. The way I am currently doing it is with a wrap function, but I have a problem because even if I am logged in with a user who has ifAdmin=True for project "x," and I go to project "x" page and try to edit project, I still get the HttpResponseRedirect('/').

model:

```
class uProjects(models.Model):
   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ifAccepted = models.BooleanField(null = True, blank=False, default=False)
    #ifLeader = models.BooleanField(null = False, blank=False)
    ifAdmin = models.BooleanField(null = True, blank=False, default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ',' + self.project.name
```

views.py

```
def admin_check(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        name = kwargs.get('name')  
        if uProjects.objects.filter(title=name, user=user, ifAdmin=True).exists():
             return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

  return wrap

@admin_check
def update(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pr_form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                    request.FILES,
                                    instance=request.project.name)
   
        if pr_form.is_valid():
            pr_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'This project has been updated.')
            return redirect('project')
        
    else:
        pr_form = ProjectUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'pr_form': pr_form
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/updateproject.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',v.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/<int:id>/',v.profile, name='profile1'),
    path('profile/',v.profile1, name='profile'),
    path('home/',v.home, name='home'),
    path('noti/',n.Notifications, name='noti'),
    path('invite/',n.invite, name='invite'),
    path('accept/<str:name1>/<int:id>/', n.accept, name='accept'),
    path('project/<str:name>/request/<int:id>', n.request, name= 'request'),
    path('allow/<str:name1>/<int:id>/', n.allow, name = 'allow'),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('', include('projects.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    #url(r'^updateprofile', v.updateprofile),
    path('updateprofile/', v.updateprofile, name='updateprofile'),
    path('createproject/', p.createProject, name='createproject'),
    path('project/<str:name>/', p.project, name='project'),
    path('editproject/', p.update, name="editproject"),
    path('agree/', include('Notifications.urls')),
]
```

projects.models.py

````
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    bPic = models.ImageField(default='defaultproban.jpg', upload_to='project_banner')
    logo = models.ImageField(default='defaultlogo.jpg', upload_to='project_logo')
    dep_choice1 = (
        ('Behavioral Sciences and Leadership', ('Behavioral Sciences and Leadership')),
        ('Chemistry and Life Science', ('Chemistry and Life Science')),
        ('Civil and Mechanical Engineering', ('Civil and Mechanical Engineering')),
        ('Electrical Engineering and Comptuer Science', ('Electrical Engineering and Comptuer Science')),
        ('English and Philosophy', ('English and Philosophy')),
        ('Foreign Languages', ('Foreign Languages')),
        ('Geography and Environmental Engineering', ('Geography and Environmental Engineering')),
        ('History', ('History')),
        ('Law', ('Law')),
        ('Mathematical Sciences', ('Mathematical Sciences')),
        ('Physics and Nuclear Engineering', ('Physics and Nuclear Engineering')),
        ('Social Sciences', ('Social Sciences')),
        ('Systems Engineering', ('Systems Engineering')),
        ('Independent', ('Independent')),
    )
    department = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=dep_choice1,
        default='Independent',
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True)
    purpose=models.TextField()
    tag_choice = (
        ('Data Analysis' , ('Data Analysis')),
        ('3D Printing' , ('3D Printing')),
        ('Robotics' , ('Robotics')),
        ('Coding' , ('Coding')),
        ('Frauds' , ('Frauds, AKA Law majors')),
    )

    projectTag = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices=tag_choice,
        default='Frauds',
    )

    look = (
        ('motivated cadets with niche expertise.', ('Expert Cadets')),
        ('cadets who want to learn and help.', ('Any cadet who wants to help')),
        ('an engineering cadet.', ('Engineering Cadet')),
        ('a cadet with a scientific background.', ('Scientific background')),
        ('cadets with programming experience.', ('Coding Background')),
       
    )
    
    lookingFor = models.CharField(
        max_length=75,
        choices=look,
        default='an engineering cadet,',
    )

    recruit = (
        ('Yes', ('Yes')),
        ('No', ('No')),
    )

    recruiting = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=recruit,
        default='Yes',
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "projects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name```

This code doesn't work with the provided code because when I am logged in with a user who has ifAdmin = True for a uProject, and I try to edit the project page associated with that uProject, I am returned the HttpResponseRedirect('/')
````

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly how django works, try it:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('editproject/<str:name>', p.update, name="editproject"),
    ...
]
```

In this `name = kwargs.get('name')` we always have `None` and django tries to find uProjects with `None` title, which does not exist in db.

Comment: Thank you for the input. My dilemma if I try to do this is that I get an error: "NoReverseMatch at /project/Investment Algorithms/
Reverse for 'editproject' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editproject/(?P<name>[^/]+)$']" Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: First, I would start by transferring such patterns as `path('', include('main.urls'))` to the end of the file. Second, try to open `editproject/somethingname` URL, but not `editproject`

Comment: When I try to open ```editproject/[a project that the user I'm logged in with has ifAdmin = True]``` I get an HttpResponseRedirect to the home page because somehow the user didn't pass the test. Which leads me back to the original problem.

Comment: Set a break point and check what contains in your `name` variable, then do query like `uProjects.objects.filter(title=name, user=user, ifAdmin=True)` and check what was returned, then you can answer your own question

Comment: Great point. So, I tried this and for some reason the error was that field 'id' expected a number but got the string I entered for my username. Why is this?